# How can i join words in an array to form a single line sentence without it spanning to a new line

Tags: python, string

i have tried this:

```
mystring=input()

mystring=mystring.split()
for word in mystring:
    newword=word[1:]+word[0]
    print("".join(newword))
```

Input:

```
hello world
```

the output for the above input:

```
elloh
orldw
```

The expected output should be:

```
elloh orldw
```

Comment: No need to join, it's already a string. Just provide a different `end` param: `print(newword, end=" ")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current approach is that you are just printing each word once in the loop, which by default is also printing a newline character.  You seem to have the idea of populating a new list with the partially reversed version of each word.  If so, then define a list and use this approach:

```py
mystring = input()

words = mystring.split()
words_out = []

for word in words:
    newword = word[1:] + word[0]
    words_out.append(newword)

print(" ".join(words_out))
```

For an input of `hello world`, the above script prints:

```
elloh orldw
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass a parameter " " to join in order to concatenate the list elements like:

```
mystring=input()

mystring=mystring.split()
newstring = ' '.join(mystring)
print(newstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the input.

```
mystring="hello world"
mystring=[text[1:]+text[0] for text in mystring.split()]
print(" ".join(mystring))
```

Comment: I saw all reversed. Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```py
myString = "hello world".split()
for word in myString:
    new = word[1:]+word[0]
    print(new, end=" ", flush=True)
```

Output:

```
elloh orldw
```

Or you can do this:

```py
myString = "hello world".split()
new_word = []

for word in myString:
    new = word[1:]+word[0]
    new_word.append(new)

print(*new_word, sep=" ")
```

Output:

```
elloh orldw
```

One Line Solution:

```
print(*[word[1:]+word[0] for word in input().split()], sep=" ")
```

Input - hello world
Output:`elloh orldw`

Answer (score 0):

You can code as below for one liner function:

```
print(" ".join([(word[1:] + word[0]) for word in mystring.strip().split()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you were wrong here: `print("".join(newword))`. It's wrong since the print should be outside the loop, and even if you do that the join function has nothing to join as every time you run the loop the `newword` variable is assigned with new value and loses the previous value, hence there is nothing to join. So try this bit of code it will definitely help:

```
mystring=input()
mystring=mystring.split()
final=[]
for word in mystring:
  newword=word[1:]+word[0]
  final.append(newword)

print(" ".join(final))
```